# Is using java file io fine in multithreaded and high load scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, file, thread-safety

I have a scenario where for every request I need to open a file and read it . This file will be mostly small in size. There is a constraint that the node I am on doesnt have database . so data can be stored in files only. Will there be any issues when multiple requests execute parallely on same file ? Are there any alternatives?  I am using java and doing file IO using java.

Comment: If you are only reading the files concurrently - then there will be no issues.  If you have only disk access, then you should consider embedded databases such as H2, Derby, etc. - much better than plain files.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, Wouldn't file opening and closing cause performance issues?

Comment: Assume, I dont have liberty to cache it because of restrictions.

Comment: File opening and closing doesn't necessarily lead to performance problems - an OS is usually rather good at it and can open / close thousands of files per second (especially if it is always the same file - the OS will cache it for you)

Comment: @ThomasKläger, you can enter this comment as answer. will be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File opening and closing doesn't necessarily lead to performance problems - an OS is usually rather good at it and can open / close thousands of files per second (especially if it is always the same file - the OS will cache it for you)